# How to make link's background follows cursor?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, hover, gradient

I'm trying to make animated links. Depending from which side cursor enter the link - its background should appear from bottom to top or from top to bottom. Links should have effect like background follows cursor.

I managed to make background appear from bottom to top, but why it does not work vice versa?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nosdmitry/pen/YzVQabG?editors=1111)

```
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">test link 1</li>
  <li class="list__item">test link 2</li>
  <li class="list__item">test link 3</li>
  <li class="list__item">test link 4</li>
  <li class="list__item">test link 5</li>
</ul>

.list__item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.from-top {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.from-bottom {
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}


const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');
list.forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('mouseover', (evt) => {
     if (evt.offsetY < 10) {
       console.log('top', evt.offsetY);
       item.classList.add('from-top');
     } else {
       console.log('bottom', evt.offsetY);
       item.classList.add('from-bottom');
     }
   });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', (evt) => {
    item.classList.remove('from-top');
    item.classList.remove('from-bottom');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand whats going on here I suggest you to figure out which property you actually trying to animate.

I modified a bit your pen to make it work.
[Here](https://codepen.io/ishaba/pen/eYWRoNo) you can see that the main property in my case is `background-size`

The reason why it do not work in your example with **from top** direction is that you animating `background-size` as well as `background-position` which initial value is `top` and you trying to animate from `top` to `top` – that's why nothing happens in this case and works vice versa with **from bottom** direction because there animation goes from initial `top` to `bottom` which you defined in `.from-bottom` class.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed!:)